# Moving boundaries for Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, continuity, stopping-times

Let $\tau(X_t)$ be the first-passing time to the moving boundary $a(t)$ for an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process $X_t$. I wonder how general an $a$ can be allowed in order to guarantee that $\tau$ becomes continuous almost everywhere with respect to the measure induced by $X_t$ (Wiener, correct?). I would be very grateful for any references!

Comment: I'm confused.  The stopping time $\tau$ is a random variable on your sample space, which doesn't necessarily carry a topology, so I don't know what you mean by "continuous".  Can you explain?  Also, Wiener measure usually refers to the measure on $C([0,T])$ or $C([0,\infty))$ induced by Brownian motion, not Ornstein-Uhlenbeck.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I'm new to this field. By "continuous" I mean, intuitively speaking, that a "small" difference between two sample paths should imply a "small" difference between their first-passing times seen as a functional on these processes. I'm primarily interested in the first-passing times, rather than stopping times, although these are also interesting. What is the appropriate measure for Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes?

Comment: I see.  So to rephrase, consider $C([0,\infty))$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets, and the map $\tau : C([0,\infty)) \to [0,\infty]$ defined by $\tau(x) = \inf \{t : x(t)=a(t)\}$.  $\tau$ is certainly not continuous.  Now $X_t$ induces a (Borel) measure $\mu$ on $C([0,\infty))$ (which we could call Ornstein-Uhlenbeck measure).  Then your question is whether $\tau$ is continuous $\mu$-almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, but in hindsight I would probably like to replace $C([0,\infty])$ by $D([0,b])$ where $b$ may be finite or infinite, and where $D$ is Skorokhod space. I would then like to change the formulation of $\tau$ slightly so that $$\tau_a(X)=\inf\{s|X(s)\ge a(s)\} = \inf\{s|X(s)-a(s)\ge 0\}=\tau_0(X-a)$$. This should reduce the problem to the well-known constant boundary problem. Or?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat embarrassingly, it seems I found the answer (please correct me if I'm wrong).

An excellent book on the subject is Whitt: Stochastic Process Limits (Springer 2002). It provides nice intuition together with a useful toolbox for attacking these problems.

The keyword appears to be *Skorokhod topologies*. Elements in this space are continuous with jumps, or more precisely speaking, cadlag functions. A nice property of these functions is that they can be described as limits of sequences of piecewise constant functions with jumps. Whitt explains very nicely how properties such as first-passing time are analyzed by considering convergent sequences. It seems clear from this that *cadlag* boundaries will be fine, since OU processes are continuous (and thereby cadlag).